# how to use method in Widgets in call log in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

- How to make call logs flutter
- I tried several ways call this method in text widget in Listview.builder()
- But it print in Debug Console
- I try to shown in Listview()
- I'm using `call_log: ^3.0.3`

  ```
  void _callLogs() async {
    Iterable<CallLogEntry> entries = await CallLog.get();
    for (var log in entries) {
    print(log.name);
           }
          }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```dart
FutureBuilder<Iterable<CallLogEntry>>(
   future: _callLogs,
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Iterable<CallLogEntry>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
         ... /// fill your listview with snapshot.data...
      }
   }
)


future<Iterable<CallLogEntry>> _callLogs() async => CallLog.get();
```

Comment: future: _callLogs show this error "The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Iterable<CallLogEntry>>?'"